# Text not storing from summernote in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I want to integrate summernote (summernote.org) in a textarea and save in database.

my view code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3"><label>Estado</label>
<textarea name="textfield4" id="textfield4"></textarea></div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
<input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">
```

my js code:

```
              <script>
           $('#textfield4').summernote({

            height:200
           });
             </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please write me what is the error message if its not working, I have modified your javascript code, replace the yourformid with actual form id and try, I assume you have a form with action defined in the html,

```
$(function(){

$('#estado').summernote(
{

  toolbar: [
                ['headline', ['style']],
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
                ['textsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['alignment', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'lineheight']],
            ],

height:120
});

$("#yourformid").submit(function(e) {
     var self = this;
     e.preventDefault();

     var estado = $('#estado').code();
     $("#textfield4").html(estado); //populate text area
     self.submit();
     return false; 
});
});
```

make sure your token being passed or use the following method to generate token,

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()
```

Comment: i am getting the following error: ` Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function(anonymous function) @ myplace:1565  dispatch @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:5  v.handle @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:5`

Comment: please add this line of code before `var estado = $('#estado').code();`
add this `$('#estado').destroy();` and try,

Comment: error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).destroy is not a function

Comment: i think its     $('#estado').summernote('destroy'); but still same error  : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function

Comment: try to change your version of summer note to latest and the jquery verision suggested on summer note docs,

Comment: i've changed jquery link as given in summernote doc .....but still the same error

Comment: you donot have to repeat `.summernote('code');`  because it is already an instance of summer note , so you can directly call $("editorId").code()

Comment: its must be conflicting with any other js libraries you are using, try it with a plain html and php page, definitively it works, can you remove all other js libraries except, jquery and summer note, and try to see whether it works

Comment: when i was using .summernote('code) .. a new row was created in database  but only estado field was showing empty.

Comment: ok show me your controller code, did you debug the post data to see whether the text area content being passed

Comment: dump the $estado = $request['textfield4']; and see whether you receive the value from your form

Comment: ok, show me your full view code,js,controller and model code,

Comment: route code: Route::post('/account',[

'uses' => 'AccountController@account',
'as' => 'account'


 ]);

Comment: you are repeating the `name="textfield4"` in two places, you must have unique name for each html input, in your case the name is repeated for a text area and an input in the line `<div><br><label>Also Known As:</label></br><input type="text" name="textfield4"></br></div>`   which causes you to receive empty value,

Comment: oh ho...tnx a lot.....but why the input is saved with <p> </p> tag  in the database.

Comment: ok, because summer note is an html text editor, if you want to escape html and just save the plain text, then use php striptags fuction or laravel escape function.. donot forget to thumbs up for my answer..

Answer (score 2):

You should write your code in .ready() function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#textfield4').summernote();
});
```

Comment: ty it worked but data is not save in table. 
my route file:  http://laravel.io/bin/vB61v

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a div to render summer not and populate a hidden text area with the summer note content before you submit the form, see the example bellow,

```
<div class="panel-body no-padding">
                <textarea  style="display: none;" name="emailmessage" id="emailmessage"></textarea>
                <div class="editor-summernote" id="emailmessage_editor"></div>
            </div>
```

then convert the div to render summer note editor as following

```
$('.editor-summernote').summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['headline', ['style']],
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
                ['textsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['alignment', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'lineheight']],
            ],
            height: 120
        });
```

and before submit your form for server side processing, use jquery to populate the summer note content to a hidden text area,

```
   $("#btn-send-message").on("click",function(event) {

            var email_body = $('#emailmessage_editor').code();
            $("#emailmessage").html(email_body); //populate text area
   });
```

at last you can get the data in your laravel controller by `$request->input('emailmessage')`

Comment: sry but still not working.my view code: http://laravel.io/bin/Gy2Bm 
my js code:http://laravel.io/bin/bEom5